# Accelerated mobile page Testing in live or local environment

Tags: amp-html

How should i implement Amp pages in my application so that if it is opened in mobile then Amp page to be load otherwise normal page to be load.

My application is bulid in zend framework.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1) Either you go with a UA Switcher and serve dynamically according to the user agent you got.

2) [My preference] You go AMP only and don't serve anything dynamically.
(Saves you time because you don't have to maintain two versions, no GoogleBot hassle ... )